# What do these JGoodies FormLayout constraints mean?

Tags: java, layout, jgoodies

What does the following code mean?

```
FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout("fill:5dlu:g, 5dlu, 20dlu", "pref");
```

I'm interested to know what the `FormLayout` attributes mean.

Comment: You might discover your answer amongst [these hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=FormLayout+site%3Ajgoodies.com).

Comment: The syntax is explained in the manual at http://www.jgoodies.com/articles/forms.pdf

Comment: @Peter: Would you care to make this into an answer by extracting the explanation from the manual?

Comment: No, not really. Why do you think it would be helpfull duplicate info from other sites ?

Comment: @PeterMmm: agree that duplication is bad but you can answer with the link so we can close this question :).

Comment: @PeterMmm: The reason duplication would've been nice is that SO aims to be a reference site, not to mention that the link you gave is now dead, and the existing "documentation" is severely lacking. I, for one, would love a question about the FormLayout syntax and an answer that explains it in detail...